# Import Eclipse Quantum Bookmark File

Tags: eclipse

Anyone know how to import a QuantumDB 'bookmarks.xml' file into Eclipse?  The export feature allowed me to export my Quantum bookmarks, however it does not appear to have an import function that allows to import the bookmarks file. I am using Eclipse Helios and the latest version of the QuantumDB plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Database Bookmarks" view of Quantum DB  perspective, there is small "down arrow" in the title bar. When you click it, it shows a menu with the option "Import Bookmarks". Target the xml file generated by your previous export and it just works.

Regards,
Seb